# Create beautiful websites with "text free images"?

Tags: website-design

Most websites have images with text embedded into the images.
Shure, they look great, but when it comes to translation
into other languages, it immediately gets painful to maintain.

Are there any examples of modern beautiful static websites,
2 - 5 pages, fixed with, top navigation, footer, 1 - 2 columns,
using only CSS, text and "images without text" ?

Comment: Are you looking for a template? Or for a CSS tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some CSS tutorials, you would find very interesting tips about using @font-face (so you can embed nice fonts into your page and keep your design great while accessible and easy to translate).

Follow two links:
 - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog
 - http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freecsstemplates.org/